# $watch in angularJS is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch, ng-controller

In my controller I want to be notified when a variable value is changed. My requirement is when value of a variable will change a function will be invoked. So I am using `$watch`. My code is as follow.

```
var Canvas = angular.module('canvas');

Canvas.controller("excelOperation",function($scope,Data,SharedData,$http){

    $scope.tbody=$scope.$parent.shared.previews;

     $scope.$watch('$parent.shared.previews',function(newVal,oldVal){
        console.log("WORKING");
     })

     setInterval(function(){
         console.log($scope.$parent.shared.previews);
     },1000)

    /**
     * Populate table function to populate excel table
     */
    $scope.populateTable=function()
    {

    }
})
```

`angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("page"), ['canvas']);`

But issue is `$watch` is working only when I refresh my page. Though the `setInterval` is printing the changed value of the variable `$watch` is not being invoked.

**N.B. `$scope.$parent.shared.previews` is an object**

What am I doing wrong?
And what I told to achieve, is this a good way to do?

Comment: You should use $parent.shared.previews not $scope.$parent.shared.previews. in both place in watch and setinterval

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: can you pust your complete code

Comment: $watch is monitoring value changes in scope. So be sure value must be change.

Comment: Added more code. If you need more code I can provide you :)

Comment: My setInterval showing me that value is changed.

Comment: You shoud make changes in variable inside setinterval

Comment: When is your "previews" changing ? Is it changing just once when you load the page first time or later also ?

Comment: No setInterval i have added to check if variable value is really changed or not. And it is showing me in console that value is changed but $watch at the same time not being invoked.

Comment: It is changing from parent controller when I am doing some event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are watching a object's property change, deep watch is required. Second, to watch parent scope variable, maybe you'd better write like this `$scope.$parent.$watch(...)`.

```
var deepWatch = true;
$scope.$watch('$parent.shared.previews', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log("WORKING");
}, deepWatch);
```

Comment: Just perfect. Thank you. :)

Comment: So I added what is my purpose to use this. Calling the populateTable function when variable is changed. So is using a $watch is good approach.